# Перегрузка java-методов List разного типа

Tags: java, коллекции, перегрузка-операторов

Добрый день!

Насколько корректным является перегрузка метода `List<Type>` 'ом, при различных `Type`,

```
RetrunType1 func(List<Type1> arg);
ReturnType2 func(List<Type2> arg);
```

При условии, что функции возвращают разные объекты и `Type1!=Type2`.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот код даже не скомпилируется, поскольку оба метода будут иметь одну и ту же сигнатуру аргументов, а в Java нет перегрузки методов по возвращаемому значению.

**Обновление**

Только что проверил на версиях 1.5 — 1.8. Везде компилятор выдаёт одну и ту же ошибку — "name clash: methods have the same erasure". Как вам удаётся это скомпилировать — неизвестно, ведь `type erasure` для дженериков работал всегда с момента их появления в принципе, т.е. с 1.5.

Comment: на jdk1.6 собирается и даже выполняется, выше - уже никак

Comment: Только что проверил на версиях 1.5 — 1.8. Везде компилятор выдаёт одну и ту же ошибку — "name clash: methods have the same erasure". Как вам удаётся это скомпилировать — неизвестно, ведь `type erasure` для дженериков работал всегда с момента их появления в принципе, т.е. с 1.5.

Comment: спокойно собирается на 1.6.0_45, на других версиях - никак. Я и сам, мягко говоря, не понимаю - как . Проект не мой, надо разобраться в этом волшебстве.

Comment: похоже, вот оно http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435779/differing-behaviour-between-java-5-6-when-overloading-generic-methods и https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367686
так что там оно было, но потом решили, что это плохо и выпилили:)) Ибо не нужно.

Comment: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6182950

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно нормальная практика. В библиотеках java такое используется направо и налево.

**update:**

Пример - открываем самую что не на есть стандартную библиотеку в java - [java.lang.Math](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Math.java#Math) и смотрим на методы abs, min, max, round и много других. исправление. Вот только generic'и в java никудышние... И для списков List оно не заработает.

Comment: > там не список, но это не имеет значения

Это как раз-таки имеет значение, поскольку после `type erasure` и `List<Type1>` и `List<Type2>` будут иметь одну сигнатуру — `List<Object>`.

Comment: ах да,  в java так и не запили нормальные дженерики.